# Simple real life problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ratio

Let say my girlfriend makes $2000$ Euros per month and I make $3400$ Euros, let say all our living costs sum up to $1540$ Euros.
How can i calculate how much each of us must pay (off the $1540$ Euros) so as our participation is proportional to our income?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your net income per month is 5400 euros so since she make 2000 euros that is 37% of your total income so she should pay 37% of your total expenses. $1540*.37 = 570.37$ per month as her portion of the expenses your portion would be $3400/5400 = .63$, $ 1540*.63 = 969.62 $. If you sum the two together you can then see it works out  $570.37 + 969.62 = 1539.99$ ( 1 cent got lost to rounding).

Answer (score 0):

Write down the equations that must be satisfied. Let $x$ be the amount you pay and $y$ the amount your girlfriend pays.

One equation is simple: $x+y=1540$, since you must pay the whole costs. The other equation comes from the proportions that must be satisfied:

$$x:y = 3400 : 2000$$
Which can also be written as $$\frac xy = \frac{3400}{2000}$$

Answer (score 0):

The total income is $2000 + 3400 = 5400$ euros.  Since your girlfriend makes only $2000$ euros (sexist!), she makes $\frac{2000}{5400} = .37...$ (roughly $37 \% $) of the income, which means she should only pay $37 \% $ of the rent.

Then, she should only pay $1540 *.37 = 569.80 $ euros, roughly.

Comment: I am not sexist, if i were her manager i would give her a raise immediately :) Anyways thanks

Comment: @ThomasC. Hahaha

Comment: What makes you think theyre working the same job and should have equal pay lol, I'd be so lucky to have my girlfriend working the same job as me and with me